# How can I start using content of a Drive file before it is fully downloaded?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios-simulator, google-drive-api

Am created one apps for ipad.. its already have view part.. In that am integrated google drive for list files. After listing when the user clicks to view files its going to download and then viewed by user.

Upto complete download user cant open the book. If that file content too large it takes too much time. Is it there any other way when user click file to open instantly.. or it shows 2 or 3 pages first after that remaining pages loads in background.

Comment: When you say the user clicked the file you mean he opens it with the iOS Google Drive application or did you implement a file explorer on your application yourself?

Comment: Its not a google drive application.. Its our own application..  @Nivco

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices. For instance you could download the content pieces by pieces using the [`Range` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2). The other possibility is to stream the response object (in Java I would do that by reading bytes in the InputStream of the response as they come). Too bad my lack of Objective-C skills don't allow me to help you further.